# Set value of pixels in a "Windows Form Application" using Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am making a graphics engine for my computer science class.  I chose to use C++ (which I've never used before).  I am using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE, and I like the idea of the "windows form application" as the controller for the gui, but how can I tell my window that VS creates for me what color specific pixels should be?

Or even better, can I do 2D graphics with it already? Such as drawing lines or

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, with C++ you can use GDI+ (GDIPlus) to draw any thing.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx